# Length of bytes changes after converting it to String

Tags: java, string, byte

I want to convert bytes to String for encryption purpose and then I want to retrieve same bytes for decryption. But the problem is, after generating 16 byte of IV, I convert it to String and when I try to get the same byte from String, the length of bytes changes. Below is the sample program to reproduce the issue.

```
package com.prahs.clinical6.mobile.edge.util;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
    rand.nextBytes(bytes);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(bytes);
    System.out.println("length of bytes before converting to String: " + ivSpec.getIV().length);
    String ibString = new String(ivSpec.getIV());
    System.out.println("length of bytes after converting to String: " + ibString.getBytes().length);
  }
}
```

Please can any one confirm why it is such behavior and what I need to modify in order to get the same length of byte i.e: 16 in this case.

Comment: Why are you converting these random bytes to a `String`?

Comment: Don't pass to string, because of the encoding, keeping bytes is the best way to get your algorithm to work. Don't look for tricky way to solve YOUR strange solution : avoid your strange solution.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is just the sample code. I am converting the bytes to string because I want to concatenate multiple values of string and make one encrypted response. And would use this values during decryption.

Comment: @azro This is not the complete implementation. It might look strange as of now but the main point is problem which I am facing. Skip the solution which I would be implementing.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `String` is meant to store unicode text. The random bytes you get from a `SecureRandom` are not text. You'll have to be more specific about what you're trying to do to get further help.

Comment: As a randomly generated IV will contain a lot of bytes that cannot encoded as string (think of #00) you should NOT convert it to a string this way. If you want to concatenate data do it on byte[] basis. If you need to transport them (e.g. via mail) please encoded the byte array to Base64 and later decode it back to a byte array for later usage.

Comment: What I mean is : you might though you need to resolve that problem (the String one) BUT the better way would be to AVOID that at all. You can see that as the comment you can received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not convert a randomly generated byte array to a string as there are a lot of values that cannot get encoded to a string -
just think of x00.

The usual way of "converting" such a byte array to a string is the **Base64 encoding** of the byte array. This will lengthen the string about 1/3 but you can lossless redecode the string to the byte array.

Please note that you should not use `Random` but `SecureRandom` as source of those data.

output:

```
length of bytes before converting to String: 16
ivBase64: +wQtdbbbFdvrorpFb6LRTw==
length of bytes after converting to String: 16
ivSpec equals to ivRedecoded: true
```

code:

```
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Random rand = new SecureRandom();
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
        rand.nextBytes(bytes);
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(bytes);
        System.out.println("length of bytes before converting to String: " + ivSpec.getIV().length);
        //String ibString = new String(ivSpec.getIV());
        String ivBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ivSpec.getIV());
        System.out.println("ivBase64: " + ivBase64);
        byte[] ivRedecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ivBase64);
        //System.out.println("length of bytes after converting to String: " + ibString.getBytes().length);
        System.out.println("length of bytes after converting to String: " + ivRedecoded.length);
        System.out.println("ivSpec equals to ivRedecoded: " + Arrays.equals(ivSpec.getIV(), ivRedecoded));
    }
}
```